# Polymer - Iterating over object in template

Tags: javascript, html, templates, polymer, web-component

According to the [polymer docs](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/expressions.html#named-scopes), an object or array can be iterated over using the `repeat` statement in a `<template>`:

> "expression" can be a simple identifier, a path or a full expression (including Object and Array literals).

After testing, however, it seems as though the repeat statement only works with arrays, and not with objects:

http://jsbin.com/oqotUdE/4/edit

Am I doing something incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs there are imprecise. The general nature of expressions is explicated but I don't believe it intends to say you can iterate over objects with repeat.

I believe only Arrays are support for iteration at this time, although there is talk of possibly supporting NodeLists also.

Answer (score 7):

I recently ran into this issue and got around it by using a filter which returns `Object.keys(obj)`. Below is a simple example of how to do so (maybe there is a much better way, if so, enlighten me please)...

```
<template repeat="{{item in obj | getKeys}}">
  <span>Key: {{item}}</span>
  <span>Value: {{obj[item]}}</span>
</template>

...etc...

<script>
Polymer('my-element', {
  // yes i know, instantiate arrays/objects in the created method,
  // but this is just an example
  obj : {}, 

  // my custom filter function to use in looping objects
  getKeys : function(o){
    return Object.keys(o);
  }

});
</script>
```

Of course you can get more complex, checking for data types and making sure its an object. Below is a recursive version that loops through infinite nested objects (again, if there is a simpler way, let me know)

```
<template if="{{obj}}" id="root" bind="{{obj as o}}">

  <ul>

    <template repeat="{{item in o | getKeys}}">
      <li>

        <span class="key">{{item}}</span>

        <template if="{{o[item] | isNotObject}}">
          <span class="value">{{o[item]}}</span>
        </template>

        <template if="{{o[item] | isObject}}">
          <template ref="root" bind="{{o[item] as o}}"></template>
        </template>

      </li>
    </template>

  </ul>

</template>

...etc...

<script>
Polymer('object-view', {

  obj : {},

  getKeys : function(o){
    return Object.keys(o);
  },

  isObject : function(v){
    return typeof(v) === "object";
  },

  isNotObject : function(v){
    return typeof(v) !== "object";
  }

});
</script>
```

This certainly works (for me), to loop through objects (*and arrays*, actually). Although, I'm not completely happy with the use of `Object.keys`. I'll be very encouraged to see support for object iteration soon in polymer.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for the newest versions of Polymer >= 1.0. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/37913642/6277151