# polymer template repeat field names

Tags: polymer

How can I dynamically get all the fields of this rows array objects using a polymer repeat template?

```
rows = [{
  "field1":"test1",
  "field2":"test2",
  "field3":"test3",
  "field4":"test4"
}]

<template repeat="{{data in rows}}">
   {{data.field1}}
   {{data.field2}}
   {{data.field3}}
   {{data...}}
</template>
```

Comment: See this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22211597/polymer-iterating-over-object-in-template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/thTzQepPezI5VyCwtrq7?p=preview) shows two examples:

1. How to refresh a repeat using a filter parameter. Less overhead and
   simple to implement. It's recommended to use event actions over
   observers where possible,
2. How to observe an Object as an Array (based from this issue comment
   Polymer/polymer-expressions#11 (comment))

```
<!-- parameters passed to filters are observed, so changing refresh updates the repeat -->
<template repeat="{{key in objectData | toKeys(refresh)}}">
  {{ objectData[key] }}
</template>
```

```
Polymer({
  refresh: 0, // update this value to refresh the repeat
  toKeys: function(input) {
    if (!input) return;
    return Object.keys(input);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Dodgy request...

I tried and my best luck was something like this:

```
<polymer-element name="x-for-in">
    <template>
        <template repeat="{{field in keys}}">
            {{obj[field]}}
        </template>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            obj : null,
            keys : [],
            created : function () {
                this.obj = {
                    field1 : 1,
                    field2 : 2,
                    field3 : 3
                };
                this.keys = Object.keys(this.obj);
            }
        })
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

`OUTPUT : 1,2,3`

BTW: I'm not 100% sure what you meant in description, because your code says rows - is array of objects, while you're saying rows is an object....

Anyway so far so good, example above should give an idea.

BTW2: `{{data is rows}}` where rows is an object - will not work, because it's essentially a javascript `for in`. polymer restricts such things as I understand

Comment: ok thanks I requested a new keys feature to make it more easy :) https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/1062

Comment: Alternately, create a local reference to the `keys` method: `keys: Object.keys` and use the method in the binding: `{{field in keys(obj)}}`. More dynamic.

Comment: `{{field in keys(obj)}}` @DocDude Damn that's smart!

Comment: I found a issue with this, namely it does not detected changes to obj